# superfish drop-down displaying underneath text of another div

Tags: html, css, superfish

I had a problem with the drop-down menu displaying behind a div, but that is fixed, now it is being overlapped by the text of another div:

[alt text http://cl.ly/d9bd4af6e533bbce8cdf/content](http://cl.ly/d9bd4af6e533bbce8cdf/content)

This only happens in IE7, I imagine it does in IE6 as well, but did not test in IE6.

I set the z-index of the div's it drop-downs over to z-index:1; and the z-index of the drop-down is set to 2.

Works fine in google chrome and firefox.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: fixed w/ .sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
z-index:1000;
}

http://cl.ly/653d11732d301548384a

Comment: I would check IE6 (if you want IE6 to work that is) because IE7 and IE6 have some very different behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
position: relative;
```

To your "Activity Wall" div.

z-index attribute won't work if your selector isn't positionned.

And the reference is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be attributable to your page elements not [having layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).  This is an odd issue with versions of Explorer.  The linked article has more in-depth information, but try adding a `height` parameter to your page elements if possible, and see if that fixes it.